# Is increasing the max. number of instances in the same zone possible?

Tags: instance, google-compute-engine, zone

I am working on an experiment that needs a large number (~120) of Google Compute Engine instances. It does not matter how powerful each instance is. I just use n1-standard-1 instances.

The experiment needs to have all instances in the same zone, but I found that I could only create 22~23 instances in the same zone.

Would there be any way to increase that limit?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't make us guess; are you talking about the Google Compute Engine?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the Google Compute Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could request to change your default per-region quota as describe here :

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas#perregion

There is a link at the end of the doc to google docs "quote change request form"

hope that helps